# Empty JSON Object POSTING

Tags: java, json

When there is parameters to be posted , 
We do something like

`JSONObject postParams = new JSONObject("{ \"ccc\": \"20000\", \"abc\": \"21000\""}`");

```
DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes(postParams.toString());
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();
            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
            System.out.println("Post parameters : " + postParams);
            System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
```

What if there isnt any parameters , i tried doing

```
JSONObject postParams = new JSONObject("{}");
```

It failed. But the unique ID is contained inside the link

https://domain.com/ut/game/game/trade/**{UNIQUE ID HERE}**/bid

There is something i missed out i believe.

Comment: Why not just `new JSONObject();`?

Comment: I think you missed the question part...

Comment: "It failed" — What does this mean? Do you get an error?

Comment: The server returned Permission Denied

Comment: But when i do a a POST , with parameters, it's working fine, just trying to figure out the PUT

Comment: @ExplosionPills Same error as JSONObject("{}");

Comment: Why was this tagged PHP?

Comment: Is this in a web service? Can you give a bit more details about the environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no parameters then don't write anything to `conn.getOutputStream()`

I have no idea what your end-point is but this is likely the case.